What is the main reason raked wingtips are more efficient than winglets?
What is the main reason that these:

Are more efficient than these?: 

My main guess is that they improve L/D compared to winglets, as they provide more upwards lift making them more efficient.
It also would make sense if they reduced tip vortices because of the sweep and their shape reducing pressure differential, (more so than winglets).

Does this answer your question? Plus all the links in that answer.

More span is always better than winglets.  Winglets become beneficial when you are in a span constrained environment.
Any time you try to compare something in aircraft design (or anything else really), you have to really understand what you are holding constant and what you are varying.
It is nearly impossible to take two arbitrary features from two aircraft and make a direct comparison of which is better / worse -- Even though this seems like a similar comparison (the wing tip treatment of two transport category aircraft), the requirements for each aircraft are surely different -- and those differences dictate the design.
